# Выравнивание текста в ячейках таблицы

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы текст в ячейках таблицы был ровно посередине?
Чем можно заменить атрибут `text-valign:middle`.
Ячейки с `id=td_est, id=td_est2` были одинаковые по высоте.
`text-valign:middle;` не помогает.
Вот код html:

```
<table style="border-color: #363636; border-width: 1px; width: 480px;" border="1" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="tds">
<tbody>
<tr align="center">
<td id="fon"><b>Оформление визы</b></td>
<td id="pad"><b>Цена</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="td_est">Однократная</td>
<td rowspan="2" id="td_est3" align="center">
<p>3090</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="td_est2">Многократная*</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

css:

```
#td_est{
  text-valign:middle;
}
#td_est2{
  text-valign:middle;
}
#td_est3{
  margin-top:0px;
  padding-top:17px;
  background-color:#e6eed5;  
}
```

Comment: @Рома Прогер, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для ячейки

```
vertical-align: middle;
text-align:center;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
td {
  text-align:center;    /* выравнивание по-горизонтали */
  vertical-align:middle;/* выранивание по-вертикали */
}
```

Посмотрите здесь [text-align](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp), [vertical-align](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp).